# SimpleXMLIterator back to XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I have a small problem. 
First I load whole XML file into array of SimpleXMLIterator. Then I do some stuff (like selecting element, checking if where condition on element is true etc etc). After this I have output like.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLIterator)#2 (8) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(5) "bk101"
    }
    ["author"]=>
    string(20) "Gambardella, Matthew"
    ["title"]=>
    string(21) "XML Developer's Guide"
    ["genre"]=>
    string(8) "Computer"
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "44.95"
    ["publish_date"]=>
    string(10) "2000-10-01"
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["description"]=>
    string(58) "An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML."
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLIterator)#4 (8) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(5) "bk102"
    }
    ["author"]=>
    string(10) "Ralls, Kim"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "Midnight Rain"
    ["genre"]=>
    string(7) "Fantasy"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "5.95"
    ["publish_date"]=>
    string(10) "2000-12-16"
    ["description"]=>
    string(130) "A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world."
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "50"
  }
}
```

**They array represents this XML**

```
    <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price da="aaaa">44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <value>50</value>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price a="a">5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
      <value>50</value>
   </book>
```

If there any way to change that array into XML file?

NOTE: The **book root** element is not stored in array. But It's not kinda problem. I have that name of element stored in variable so I could use something like

```
for( //number of elements of array ) {
    file_put_contents($output, "<" . $element ."/>", FILE_APPEND);
    foreach(...)
       //putting content from array
    file_put_contents($output, "<" . / $element . "/>", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

So is there any chance to do this "nicely"?

Comment: I'm failing to see the point, why you would convert an XML to an array and back?

Comment: I cant use xpath() function for xml query. So I have to load whole file into array, select element from some element and for every elements check where condition. Then put the result array to other xml file.

Comment: Not sure why you think you have to convert the XML into an array for that. As you noticed you loos information if you do that. Validate you conditions on the SimpleXMLElement instances or DOM nodes.

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://php.net/SimpleXMLIterator), SimpleXMLIterator inherits from SimpleXMLElement, so has an `->asXML()` method. So do you just want `foreach ( $iterator as $element ) { echo $element->asXML(); }`? If that's not it, please could you explain your problem more clearly, including a [mcve] - at the moment, we have only part of the story (for instance, I'm not sure how you'd end up with an array of iterators, rather than just an iterator, or an array of elements).